# TS/React: View['props'] vs React.ComponentProps<typeof View>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given an existing React component (here `View`) it seems there are 2 ways I can get the type of props (in case it's not exported).

Can someone tell me the difference between these 2 distinct ways?

- Lookup type: `View['props']`
- Conditional type with inference: `React.ComponentProps<typeof View>`

Why should I use one instead of the other? Which one is the "best practice" and we should rather use? I've actually found these 2 distinct ways in popular opensource projects, wonder which one is "right".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case either one should work just as well and are unlikely to break in the future.

The conditional type is a bit more future-proof since it is maintained by the react team itself, it should always extract the corect type for properties.

The lookup type ties you to the specific `props` property of the class and will not work for functional components. While unlikely if the name of the key changes you might have problems.

Since the react definitions provide a dedicated conditional type to extract the props I would prefer that.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the lookup type did not work fine with SFC :) makes sense